# Django-Media For Each app in apps

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

How Can Make media For Each app In One Project??? For Example I Have A Project That's Name Is MyProject And Have Tow Application That's Names Are myapp1 and myapp2 And Want To Make Media For Each Application Separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need *django.contrib.staticfiles* as described here 
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/

This allows you to keep the static media required by each app within a subfolder of each app (named static) and then, at deployment time, to collate the static content of all apps to a common location using:

manage.py collectstatic